# Подключение к базе данных php на хостинге beget

Tags: php, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Я только начинаю знакомится с базой данных и хочу вывести данные из таблицы, но ничего не выводится. Помогите пожалуйста [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname= "susamo9a_gg";
$dbuser= "test1";
$dbpasswd =  "пароль бд";
$induction = mysql_connect($host,$dbname,$dbpasswd,$dbuser);
if($induction == false){
    echo 'Okey';
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test1`";
$result = mysql_query($induction, $sql);
$food = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($food)
```

Comment: У вас в коде указаны неправильные данные для подсоединения к базе. Правильные надо смотреть в панели управления хостингом.

Comment: Вы подключаетесь к БД откуда? Внешнее подключение?

Comment: Использование `mysql_` и `mysqli_` функций одновременно - ведет к ошибкам. К тому же `mysql_`-функции давно удалены, если конечно ты не на 5-й версии php. Так что начинать надо с дебага, соответственно - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нельзя использовать одновременно функции `mysql_*` и `mysqli_*`. Советую отказаться от первого и использовать второе
2. У вас в `mysql_connect()` параметры используются неправильно. Впрочем, это не так важно, если будете переходить на MySQLi. `$induction = mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpasswd,$dbname);`
3. Не используйте `if($induction == false)`. Не уверен, что оно вообще хоть в каком-то случае отработает. Лучше узнавайте явное наличие ошибки: `if(mysqli_connect_error())`
4. В следующий раз, прежде чем завать сюда вопрос, сначала посмотрите в `error.log`. Возможно, вам даже вопрос тогда задавать не придётся